# How to have static dialog fragment method to use throughout app in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created a `DialogFragment` class that I need to show from within a `onDragListener`. I tried a regular `AlertDialog` but couldn't get the activity context to be static. I tried adding this to my `onDragListener` class and to my `CustomLayoutClass` but it says that `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be referenced from a static method or that it cannot be resolved.

```
public static void showScoopDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ScoopSizeDialog editNameDialogFragment = ScoopSizeDialog.newInstance("Some Title");
    editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}
```

This is my custom onDragListener class. I need to show a dialog with edittext when the user drops an image:

```
public class ChoiceDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    boolean DEBUG = true;
    Context context;
    public String TAG = "Drag Layout:";

    public ChoiceDragListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                if(DEBUG) Log.v("here","drag started");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                int mCurX = (int) event.getX();
                int mCurY = (int) event.getY();

                if (DEBUG) Log.v("Cur(X, Y) : " ,"here ::" + mCurX + ", " + mCurY );
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                if (DEBUG)
                    Log.v("here","drag exits");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ClipData cd =  event.getClipData();
                ClipData.Item item = cd.getItemAt(0);
                String resp = item.coerceToText(context).toString();

                //view dragged item is being dropped on
                ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;

                //view being dragged and dropped
                ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

                dropped.setEnabled(false);

                //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
                Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();

                CreateProd.nsList.add(dropped.getTag().toString());

                Log.d(TAG, dropped.getTag().toString() + "added to list");

                //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
                if (tag != null) {
                    //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                    int existingID = (Integer)tag;

                    //set the original view visible again
                    ((Activity) context).findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                if (DEBUG) Log.i("drag event", "ended::" + ChoiceTouchListener.offsetX + "," + ChoiceTouchListener.offsetY);

                /**
                 * returning false so that goes to parentView onDrag function
                 */
                return false;
            //break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my custom layout:

```
public class DragLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    boolean DEBUG = true;
    AnimationDrawable blenderAnim;
    Handler handlerAnim2;
    Context context;

    private int dimensionInPixel = 200;
    int screenWidth,screenHeight;
    static float up_x=0,up_y=0;


    boolean mIsScrolling = false;

    public DragLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;

        //not to include in main program
        getDimensionsofScreen();

        setLayout();
        setViews();

    }

    private void setLayout() {
        // set according to parent layout (not according to current layout)
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rLp.topMargin = 2 * (screenHeight / 25); // calculating 1/10 of 4/5
        // screen

        this.setLayoutParams(rLp);
    }

    void setViews() {
        ImageView img2 = new ImageView(context);

        int dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (screenWidth / 5), (screenHeight / 5));
        rLp.topMargin = (screenHeight / 10);
        rLp.leftMargin = (4*screenWidth / 10);
        rLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        img2.setLayoutParams(rLp);
        img2.getLayoutParams().height = dimensionInDp;
        img2.getLayoutParams().width = dimensionInDp;
        img2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blender_anim));
        img2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener(context));
        this.addView(img2);

        blenderAnim = (AnimationDrawable)img2.getDrawable();
        blenderAnim.setOneShot(true);
        blenderAnim.stop();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDimensionsofScreen() {
        //metrics that holds the value of height and width
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();;
        ArrayList<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        vals.add(displayMetrics.widthPixels);
        vals.add(displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        return vals;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {

        int mCurX = (int) event.getX();
        int mCurY = (int) event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED || event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
            if (blenderAnim.isRunning()) {
                blenderAnim.stop();
            } else {
                blenderAnim.run();

                handlerAnim2 = new Handler();
                handlerAnim2.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                blenderAnim.stop();
                            }},
                        getAnimationDuration(blenderAnim));
            }
        }

        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP || event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {

            if (blenderAnim.isRunning()) {
                blenderAnim.stop();
            } else {
                blenderAnim.run();

                handlerAnim2 = new Handler();
                handlerAnim2.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                blenderAnim.stop();
                            }},
                        getAnimationDuration(blenderAnim));
            }

            Log.v("here", "it is :: " + mCurX + ", " + mCurY);

            View view1 = (View) event.getLocalState();
            view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ObjectAnimator animationx = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1,"translationX", mCurX - ChoiceTouchListener.offsetX-(screenWidth / 10),0.0f);
            ObjectAnimator animationy = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1, "translationY", mCurY - ChoiceTouchListener.offsetY - (screenHeight / 10), 0.0f);
            AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animSet.setDuration(500);
            animSet.playTogether(animationx,animationy);

            animSet.start();
        }

        if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP || event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED){
            if (blenderAnim.isRunning()) {
                blenderAnim.stop();
            }
        }
        return true;


    }

    private int getAnimationDuration(AnimationDrawable src) {
        int dur = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<src.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
            dur += src.getDuration(i);
        }
        return dur;
    }

    private void showScoopDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ScoopSizeDialog editNameDialogFragment = ScoopSizeDialog.newInstance("Some Title");
        editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be static?

Comment: @Karakuri I assumed the only way to show the dialog from my onDragListener class was to use a static method from another class